# How to continue to loop if there is QueryException?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I want to store some products models. I'm getting these data with curl, sometimes unexpected errors happen. But I want continue to foreach loop when this happened. How can I do that ?

```
private function storeAllModels()
{
    foreach ($this->models as $model_bundle) {
        foreach ($model_bundle as $model) {
            $source = $this->getSourceWithCurl($this->base_url . "/" . $model);
            $details = $this->getModelDetails($source);
            if ($details == "error") {
                array_push($this->errors, $model);
                continue;
            }
            try {
                $model = new Product();
                $model::forceCreate($details);
            } catch (QueryException $e) {
                array_push($this->errors, $model);
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I use try catch statement but still errors break foreach loop

Comment: what does the error says ?

Comment: column not found it says. There is problem with pattern I guess. Sometimes it gives me that error

Comment: you can solve this through checking if the table has a certain column, you get the columns like this: `$columns = Schema::getColumnListing($table);`

Comment: but this is just as a final method if you didn't find an answer, i don't honestly know how to not break the loop

Comment: try `} catch (\Exception $e) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with global exception class, which will catch all type of errors,

```
    private function storeAllModels()
{
    foreach ($this->models as $model_bundle) {
        foreach ($model_bundle as $model) {
            $source = $this->getSourceWithCurl($this->base_url . "/" . $model);
            $details = $this->getModelDetails($source);
            if ($details == "error") {
                array_push($this->errors, $model);
                continue;
            }
            try {
                $model = new Product();
                $model::forceCreate($details);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                array_push($this->errors, $model);
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand the login behind this ? QueryException class inherit from Exception class.. Why it doesn't work ?

Comment: you can either target to catch specific set of error depending on the situations, for example assume you are uploading file to server and at the same time you are saving it to database, in this scenario, we cannot be certain on what kind of errors it might cause, some time it can give your file handling errors due to permission issue etc. or it might arise db related errors, 
depending on the situations you have to decide which class to use, i guess it has impact on performance..